# Communications link failure error while deploying from Google Cloud Run with Cloud SQL:MySQL

Tags: spring-boot, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-run

Followed this link for continuous deployment using Cloud Build and GitHub actions in spring-boot app.

[petomalina.medium.com/](https://petomalina.medium.com/connecting-to-cloud-sql-from-cloud-run-dcff2e20152a)

Everything is working fine except for when service is trying to access the database using the following command to deploy.

```
gcloud run deploy my-service \
          --region europe-west1 \
          --image gcr.io/${{ secrets.GCP_PROJECT_ID }}/my-service \
          --platform managed \
          --allow-unauthenticated \
          --project ${{ secrets.GCP_PROJECT_ID }} \
          --add-cloudsql-instances [instance-name] \
          --set-env-vars DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:mysql://google/[dbname]?cloudSqlInstance=[instance-name]&socketFactory=com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory&useSSL=false
```

I have also added role for Cloud SQL client against the service account, tried using both public ip, private ip and this format
`jdbc:mysql://google/[dbname]?cloudSqlInstance=[instance-name]&socketFactory=com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory&useSSL=false`

This is my `app.prop` file:

```
spring.datasource.url=${DATASOURCE_URL}
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=pswd
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

But still it gives this error:

```
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: \
Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. \
The driver has not received any packets from the server.
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:174)
[mysql-connector-java-8.0.22.jar!/:8.0.22] com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:64)
[mysql-connector-java-8.0.22.jar!/:8.0.22] com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:836)
[mysql-connector-java-8.0.22.jar!/:8.0.22] com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:456)
[mysql-connector-java-8.0.22.jar!/:8.0.22] com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:246)
[mysql-connector-java-8.0.22.jar!/:8.0.22] com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:198) [mysql-connector-java-8.0.22.jar!/:8.0.22]
```

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

These are the dependencies added:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20160810</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I have also added this:

```
<dependency>
      <!-- MySQL Socket Factory for Cloud SQL -->
      <groupId>com.google.cloud.sql</groupId>
      <artifactId>mysql-socket-factory</artifactId> 
      <version>1.0.3</version>
</dependency>
```

And now the error has changed to this:

```
[nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet] : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception
[Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: \
Unable to acquire JDBC Connection; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: \
Unable to acquire JDBC Connection] with root cause
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
[na:1.8.0_202] at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source) 
[na:1.8.0_202] at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
[na:1.8.0_202] at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
[na:1.8.0_202] at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
[na:1.8.0_202] at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
[na:1.8.0_202] at com.mysql.cj.protocol.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:155)
[mysql-connector-java-8.0.22.jar!/:8.0.22] at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:63)
[mysql-connector-java-8.0.22.jar!/:8.0.22] at com.mysql.cj.NativeSession.connect(NativeSession.java:144)
[mysql-connector-java-8.0.22.jar!/:8.0.22] at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:956)
[mysql-connector-java-8.0.22.jar!/:8.0.22] at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:826)
[mysql-connector-java-8.0.22.jar!/:8.0.22] at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:456)
[mysql-connector-java-8.0.22.jar!/:8.0.22] at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:246)
[mysql-connector-java-8.0.22.jar!/:8.0.22] at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:198) 
[mysql-connector-java-8.0.22.jar!/:8.0.22] at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138)
[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar!/:na] at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:358)
[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar!/:na] at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:206)
[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar!/:na] at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:477)
[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar!/:na] at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:560)
[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar!/:na] at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115)
[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar!/:na] at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112)
[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar!/:na] at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122)
[hibernate-core-5.4.23.Final.jar!/:5.4.23.Final] at org.hibernate.internal.NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.java:38)
[hibernate-core-5.4.23.Final.jar!/:5.4.23.Final] at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.acquireConnectionIfNeeded(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:108)
[hibernate-core-5.4.23.Final.jar!/:5.4.23.Final] at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.getPhysicalConnection(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:138)
[hibernate-core-5.4.23.Final.jar!/:5.4.23.Final] at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.connection(StatementPreparerImpl.java:50)
[hibernate-core-5.4.23.Final.jar!/:5.4.23.Final] at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$5.doPrepare(StatementPreparerImpl.java:149)
[hibernate-core-5.4.23.Final.jar!/:5.4.23.Final] at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:176)
[hibernate-core-5.4.23.Final.jar!/:5.4.23.Final] at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.prepareQueryStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:151)
[hibernate-core-5.4.23.Final.jar!/:5.4.23.Final] at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:2104)
[hibernate-core-5.4.23.Final.jar!/:5.4.23.Final] at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:2041)
[hibernate-core-5.4.23.Final.jar!/:5.4.23.Final] at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:2019)
[hibernate-core-5.4.23.Final.jar!/:5.4.23.Final] at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:948)
[hibernate-core-5.4.23.Final.jar!/:5.4.23.Final] at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:349)
[hibernate-core-5.4.23.Final.jar!/:5.4.23.Final] at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2850)
[hibernate-core-5.4.23.Final.jar!/:5.4.23.Final] at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2832)
[hibernate-core-5.4.23.Final.jar!/:5.4.23.Final] at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2664)
[hibernate-core-5.4.23.Final.jar!/:5.4.23.Final] at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2659)
[hibernate-core-5.4.23.Final.jar!/:5.4.23.Final] at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:506)
[hibernate-core-5.4.23.Final.jar!/:5.4.23.Final] at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:400)
[hibernate-core-5.4.23.Final.jar!/:5.4.23.Final] at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:219)
[hibernate-core-5.4.23.Final.jar!/:5.4.23.Final] at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1414)
[hibernate-core-5.4.23.Final.jar!/:5.4.23.Final] at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.doList(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1565)
[hibernate-core-5.4.23.Final.jar!/:5.4.23.Final] at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1533)
[hibernate-core-5.4.23.Final.jar!/:5.4.23.Final] at org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:165)
[hibernate-core-5.4.23.Final.jar!/:5.4.23.Final] at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$PagedExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:177)
[spring-data-jpa-2.4.1.jar!/:2.4.1] at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:88)
[spring-data-jpa-2.4.1.jar!/:2.4.1] at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:155)
[spring-data-jpa-2.4.1.jar!/:2.4.1] at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:143)
[spring-data-jpa-2.4.1.jar!/:2.4.1] at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:137)
[spring-data-commons-2.4.1.jar!/:2.4.1] at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:121)
[spring-data-commons-2.4.1.jar!/:2.4.1] at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:152)
[spring-data-commons-2.4.1.jar!/:2.4.1] at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:131)
[spring-data-commons-2.4.1.jar!/:2.4.1] at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
[spring-aop-5.3.1.jar!/:5.3.1] at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:80)
[spring-data-commons-2.4.1.jar!/:2.4.1] at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
[spring-aop-5.3.1.jar!/:5.3.1] at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:371)
[spring-tx-5.3.1.jar!/:5.3.1] at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:134)
[spring-tx-5.3.1.jar!/:5.3.1] at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
[spring-aop-5.3.1.jar!/:5.3.1] at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137)
[spring-tx-5.3.1.jar!/:5.3.1] at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
[spring-aop-5.3.1.jar!/:5.3.1] at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:145)
[spring-data-jpa-2.4.1.jar!/:2.4.1] at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
[spring-aop-5.3.1.jar!/:5.3.1] at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97)
[spring-aop-5.3.1.jar!/:5.3.1] at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
[spring-aop-5.3.1.jar!/:5.3.1] at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215)
[spring-aop-5.3.1.jar!/:5.3.1] at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy121.fetchRestaurants(Unknown Source)
[na:na] at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[na:1.8.0_202] at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) 
[na:1.8.0_202] at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
[na:1.8.0_202] at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
[na:1.8.0_202] at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344)
[spring-aop-5.3.1.jar!/:5.3.1] at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208)
[spring-aop-5.3.1.jar!/:5.3.1] at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy62.fetchRestaurants(Unknown Source)
[na:na] at october.foods.services.restaurant.RestaurantService.fetchRestaurants(RestaurantService.java:100)
[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT] at october.foods.controller.restaurant.RestaurantController.fetchRestaurants(RestaurantController.java:50)
[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT] at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[na:1.8.0_202] at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) 
[na:1.8.0_202] at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
[na:1.8.0_202] at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
[na:1.8.0_202] at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:197)
[spring-web-5.3.1.jar!/:5.3.1] at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:141)
[spring-web-5.3.1.jar!/:5.3.1] at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106)
[spring-webmvc-5.3.1.jar!/:5.3.1] at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:893)
[spring-webmvc-5.3.1.jar!/:5.3.1] at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:807)
[spring-webmvc-5.3.1.jar!/:5.3.1] at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
[spring-webmvc-5.3.1.jar!/:5.3.1] at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1061)
[spring-webmvc-5.3.1.jar!/:5.3.1] at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:961)
[spring-webmvc-5.3.1.jar!/:5.3.1] at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
[spring-webmvc-5.3.1.jar!/:5.3.1] at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)
[spring-webmvc-5.3.1.jar!/:5.3.1] at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:652)
[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar!/:4.0.FR] at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
[spring-webmvc-5.3.1.jar!/:5.3.1] at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733)
[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar!/:4.0.FR] at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar!/:9.0.39] at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar!/:9.0.39] at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) 
[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.39.jar!/:9.0.39] at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar!/:9.0.39] at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar!/:9.0.39] at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
[spring-web-5.3.1.jar!/:5.3.1] at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
[spring-web-5.3.1.jar!/:5.3.1] at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar!/:9.0.39] at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar!/:9.0.39] at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
[spring-web-5.3.1.jar!/:5.3.1] at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
[spring-web-5.3.1.jar!/:5.3.1] at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar!/:9.0.39] at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar!/:9.0.39] at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
[spring-web-5.3.1.jar!/:5.3.1] at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
[spring-web-5.3.1.jar!/:5.3.1] at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar!/:9.0.39] at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar!/:9.0.39] at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar!/:9.0.39] at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) 
[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar!/:9.0.39] at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542) 
[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar!/:9.0.39] at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143) 
[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar!/:9.0.39] at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) 
[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar!/:9.0.39] at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) 
[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar!/:9.0.39] at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar!/:9.0.39] at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374) 
[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar!/:9.0.39] at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) 
[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar!/:9.0.39] at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar!/:9.0.39] at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1590) 
[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar!/:9.0.39] at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) 
[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar!/:9.0.39] at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
[na:1.8.0_202] at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
[na:1.8.0_202] at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) 
[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar!/:9.0.39] at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_202]
```

As suggested by Andrew, added ConnectionPoolContextListener,

```
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextListener;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebListener;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

import com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig;
import com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource;

@WebListener("Creates a connection pool that is stored in the Servlet's context for later use.")
public class ConnectionPoolContextListener implements ServletContextListener {
  
  private static final String CLOUD_SQL_CONNECTION_NAME = "CLOUD_SQL_CONNECTION_NAME";
  private static final String DB_USER = "DB_USER";
  private static final String DB_PASS = "DB_PASS";
  private static final String DB_NAME = "DB_NAME";

  private DataSource createConnectionPool() {
    // [START cloud_sql_mysql_servlet_create]
    // The configuration object specifies behaviors for the connection pool.
    HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();

    // The following URL is equivalent to setting the config options below:
    // jdbc:mysql:///<DB_NAME>?cloudSqlInstance=<CLOUD_SQL_CONNECTION_NAME>&
    // socketFactory=com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory&user=<DB_USER>&password=<DB_PASS>
    // See the link below for more info on building a JDBC URL for the Cloud SQL JDBC Socket Factory
    // https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-jdbc-socket-factory#creating-the-jdbc-url

    // Configure which instance and what database user to connect with.
    config.setJdbcUrl(String.format("jdbc:mysql:///%s", DB_NAME));
    config.setUsername(DB_USER); // e.g. "root", "mysql"
    config.setPassword(DB_PASS); // e.g. "my-password"

    // For Java users, the Cloud SQL JDBC Socket Factory can provide authenticated connections.
    // See https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-jdbc-socket-factory for details.
    config.addDataSourceProperty("socketFactory", "com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory");
    config.addDataSourceProperty("cloudSqlInstance", CLOUD_SQL_CONNECTION_NAME);

    // The ipTypes argument can be used to specify a comma delimited list of preferred IP types 
    // for connecting to a Cloud SQL instance. The argument ipTypes=PRIVATE will force the 
    // SocketFactory to connect with an instance's associated private IP. 
    config.addDataSourceProperty("ipTypes", "PUBLIC,PRIVATE");

    // ... Specify additional connection properties here.
    // [START_EXCLUDE]

    // [START cloud_sql_mysql_servlet_limit]
    // maximumPoolSize limits the total number of concurrent connections this pool will keep. Ideal
    // values for this setting are highly variable on app design, infrastructure, and database.
    config.setMaximumPoolSize(5);
    // minimumIdle is the minimum number of idle connections Hikari maintains in the pool.
    // Additional connections will be established to meet this value unless the pool is full.
    config.setMinimumIdle(5);
    // [END cloud_sql_mysql_servlet_limit]

    // [START cloud_sql_mysql_servlet_timeout]
    // setConnectionTimeout is the maximum number of milliseconds to wait for a connection checkout.
    // Any attempt to retrieve a connection from this pool that exceeds the set limit will throw an
    // SQLException.
    config.setConnectionTimeout(10000); // 10 seconds
    // idleTimeout is the maximum amount of time a connection can sit in the pool. Connections that
    // sit idle for this many milliseconds are retried if minimumIdle is exceeded.
    config.setIdleTimeout(600000); // 10 minutes
    // [END cloud_sql_mysql_servlet_timeout]

    // [START cloud_sql_mysql_servlet_backoff]
    // Hikari automatically delays between failed connection attempts, eventually reaching a
    // maximum delay of `connectionTimeout / 2` between attempts.
    // [END cloud_sql_mysql_servlet_backoff]

    // [START cloud_sql_mysql_servlet_lifetime]
    // maxLifetime is the maximum possible lifetime of a connection in the pool. Connections that
    // live longer than this many milliseconds will be closed and reestablished between uses. This
    // value should be several minutes shorter than the database's timeout value to avoid unexpected
    // terminations.
    config.setMaxLifetime(1800000); // 30 minutes
    // [END cloud_sql_mysql_servlet_lifetime]

    // [END_EXCLUDE]

    // Initialize the connection pool using the configuration object.
    DataSource pool = new HikariDataSource(config);
    // [END cloud_sql_mysql_servlet_create]
    return pool;
  }

  @Override
  public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent event) {
    // This function is called when the Servlet is destroyed.
    HikariDataSource pool = (HikariDataSource) event.getServletContext().getAttribute("my-pool");
    if (pool != null) {
      pool.close();
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
    // This function is called when the application starts and will safely create a connection pool
    // that can be used to connect to.
    ServletContext servletContext = event.getServletContext();
    DataSource pool = (DataSource) servletContext.getAttribute("my-pool");
    if (pool == null) {
      pool = createConnectionPool();
      servletContext.setAttribute("my-pool", pool);
    }
  }
}
```

And now the error has changed to:

```
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:826) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.22.jar!/:8.0.22]
... 33 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
com.mysql.cj.protocol.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:155) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.22.jar!/:8.0.22]
com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:63) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.22.jar!/:8.0.22]
```

It is working locally though with ConnectionPoolContextListener

Comment: Can you share your dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

`java.net.SocketTimeoutException` refers to a connection time out before a remote host's response can be received. The cause can be a local network issue, proxy or firewall incorrectly configured. If you are using a private IP, you need to check that the docker bridge network's IP range. Here is what the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/diagnose-issues#timeout) says:

> If a client cannot connect to the Cloud SQL instance using private IP, check to see if the client is using any IP in the range 172.17.0.0/16. Connections fail from any IP within the 172.17.0.0/16 range to Cloud SQL instances using private IP. Similarly, Cloud SQL instances created with an IP in that range are unreachable. This range is reserved for the docker bridge network.

To resolve some of the issues, you are experiencing, follow the documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/diagnose-issues) and post any error messages you receive, for example, you could try:

> Try the [gcloud sql connect](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/sql/connect) command to connect to your instance. This command authorizes your IP address for a short time. You can run this command in an environment with Cloud SDK and mysql client installed. You can also run this command in Cloud Shell, which is available in the Google Cloud Console and has Cloud SDK and the mysql client pre-installed.

> Temporarily allow all IP addresses to connect to an instance. For IPv4 authorize 0.0.0.0/0 (for IPv6, authorize ::/0. ***After you have tested this, please make sure you remove it again as it opens up to the world!***

Are you using [connection pools](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/manage-connections#pools)?

If not, I would create a cache of connections so that when your application needs to link to the database, it can get a temporary connection from the pool. Once the application has finished its operation, the connection returns to the pool again for later use. For this to work correctly, the connection needs to be [open and closed efficiently](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/manage-connections#opening_and_closing_connections) and not waste any resources.

Comment: I've edited the question, after following your suggestion. Can you please advise?

Comment: `java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Connection timed out exception while communicating with the server.` Have you checked the firewall rules and to see if the servers are running? They do not appear to be communicating with each other.

Comment: but it works locally with cloud SQL. Plz let me know which servers firewall rules I need to check?

Comment: If you are okay with sharing your code on GitHub it might prove helpful to diagnose the problem.